# FCM didReceiveRemoteNotification not called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, remote-notifications

I have an issue with my firebase ios app. My App is not receiving the notification and even `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called. I had recently made 2 targets, for the app. Before I had created a separate target, the notifications used to work well.

Things to clarify:

1. I have separated `Google-Info.plist` and `Info.plist` files for each target. This is verified as I can access 2 different databases and even perform explicit operations of either of them.
2. i have separate provisioning profile for each target and so are the APNS development and Production certificate.
3. All the targets are assigned the APN Auth Keys.

With all this performed I am executing the following code :

`AppDelegate.swift`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
var tokenExists = false

override init() {
    super.init()

    #if DEVELOPMENT
        print("Development Mode Started")
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleServiceDev-Info", ofType: "plist")
        guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
            else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
    #else
        print("Production Mode Started")
       FirebaseApp.configure()
    #endif

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    return true
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken

    if token != nil {
        tokenExists = true
        let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        if currUser != nil {
            let ref = FBDataservice.ds.REF_CURR_USER.child("notificationTokens")
            let val = [token! : tokenExists] as [String : Any]
            ref.setValue(val)
        }

    }

    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("ADX: Hey")
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print("foreground ------------------------  \(userInfo)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("ADX: Hey2")

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
   }
    print("foreground ------------------------  \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}



func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
}
```

With all this done, I have suddenly stopped receiving notifications for the app. I tried the console and the cloud functions both dont work.

I searched tons of question on the this forum, but found no answer.

Any help to solve this will be much appreciated.

Comment: The notification not come when app in foreground only or in not come in both foreground and background ?

Comment: Both. It used to work before. Just stopped suddenly. Tried the sample project. it works there, but this doesnt seem to work at all. I have a launch in 4 days and this stopped working.

Comment: I think the name of google file should be GoogleService-Info.plist

Comment: Well I tried that. Not working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally contacted the firebase support and turns out I had to move the FirbaseApp.configure() in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions().